# Batch script to rename [MSXEP001] Dom & Roland - Can't Punish Me EP [2000] to MSXEP001-Dom_&_Roland_-_Can't_Punish_Me_EP-FLAC-2000

Tags: batch-rename

Need a batch script to rename folders that look like this [MSXEP001] Dom & Roland - Can't Punish Me EP [2000] to looking like MSXEP001-Dom_&*Roland*-_Can't_Punish_Me_EP-FLAC-2000.

Need to remove the square brackets, add hypen between cat# and artis(s), add -FLAC- before the year and use underscore. Folders all share the same 'naming formula' and are from [MSXEP001] to [MSXEP043] so would be a bulk renaming.

Any geniuses out there that have the solution to this or can point me into the right direction?

Been decades since I used batch coding so all help is appreciated